# android difference between 480x800 hdpi and 480x800 mdpi

Tags: android

I am testing my app on the android emulator. On one screen I have a banner ad. The dimensions of the ad are 320x50.

When I start up an emulator of resolution 480x800 and 240dpi (hdpi), the banner ad is taking up the entire width of the screen.

When I start up an emulator with the same resolution but 160dpi (mdpi), the banner ad is taking up only a portion of the screen as I would expect (320 out of the 480 pixels are taken by the ad)

I'm having trouble understanding why a 480x800 device appears to have a 320dp screen width? With my understanding, displaying a 320px wide image on a 480px wide device should surely leave some space either side. I don't see how the dpi affects anything there, seeing as the resolutions are the same. I believe the higher dpi will just mean the physical device will have a smaller screen

Comment: when you say the dimensions of the ad are 320x50, do you mean dp or px? how are you creating the banner ad? is it based on a drawable? if so, which folder is the drawable in (drawable/drawable-mdpi/drawable-hdpi, etc)?

Comment: the ad size is specified using `wrap_content`, and the content is supplied by AdMob. AdMob specify that their banners are 320x50 and I'm fairly sure they have checks in place to make sure the ads aren't altered (stretched, shrunk etc) in any way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A 480x800 device at HDPI has a screen width of 320dp. As [Google's docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) say, "on a 240 dpi screen, 1 dp equals 1.5 physical pixels". So that means a resource specified as 320dp on an HDPI screen will display as 320*1.5=480 pixels.

In the case of mdpi (160dpi) I believe dp and px are 1:1, so a 320dp wide resource will display as 320*1=320 pixels. Note that it is pretty rare to have an mdpi device with 480px width, that'd be a pretty big and pixelated looking screen.

Comment: Ah, that clears things up a little bit. I thought the ratio would be 1:1 for all dpi.